# RTE schematic diagram for battery with a load

Tags: battery-charging, schematics, homework, efficiency, capacity

I am trying to draw a schematic to get information for battery round trip efficiency. My equipment is:

- 1 x 5 kW battery
- 1 x 48 VDC power supply
- 1 x 48 VDC load (const current)
- 1 x DC shunt
- 1 x multimeter

[image]

I drew the above schematic. Are my connections correct?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You forgot to include some sort of data logger, since it will take a lot of time to charge and discharge your battery. And in general, homework assignments are not welcome here.

Comment: I just have to draw the schematic drawing. It's not homework, it's some work stuff hence I wanted to confirm my schematic before fixing everything up.

Comment: Please explain what round trip efficiency is.

Comment: Without values, impossible to answer. Somewhere between 0-100 %.